# Wifi doesn't work under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I have some laptops where I noticed that the wifi is not working. The correct driver is installed. In device manager there isn't any yellow exclamation mark. The two network ( the local and the wifi ) adapters are in ok in device manager.

The problem is, if I turn the wifi on, I can't see any wifi connections where I could connect to. If I install Intel pro Wireless manager, it says there is no wifi adapter in the laptop (or something like that).

If I run the command

```
netsh wlan show interface
```

it says that the device is not ready. I have two specific laptops which I can't reinstall, because tomorrow morning someone will come for them, and on these two laptops there is two OS installed. The rest of the laptops I could reinstall, but it would be easier if I could solve the problem.

Has anyone have any idea how could I solve this?

**Update:**
I forgot to tell, that there is two OS installed on one laptop. Not on everyone, only these particular two, and on the corporate OS the wifi is not working, but on the private OS it is working, so the problem is not with the device.

**Update 2**:
I also forgot to tell, that if I run `ipconfig /all` the wireless network device is not listed.

Comment: Were there any errors during OS installation? Or go the vendor's website, download the relevant drivers and install them (preferably a clean install if the option is there). HTH

Comment: You mean to say that wifi started working after you re-installed the OS?

Comment: What laptop model are we talking about

Comment: @PratyushNalam: No, there were no errors during installing the OS. The newest drivers are installed, but I also tried to install some older ones.

Comment: @VenkatH:No. I wanted to say, that I don't want to reinstall the OS, but probably a reinstall would solve the problem.

Comment: @BroScience: They are Dell Latitude E6520 and E6320

Comment: You got the drivers from the CD or the website?

Comment: @PratyushNalam: From the website. But it is 100% sure that the correct drivers are installed.

Comment: This is a very weird problem you're having IMO

Comment: @PratyushNalam: Yes I know. I found some similar posts on the net, but no solution. Or neither one of them is working for me. Unfortunately we noticed it now, and this problems occurs on some more laptops. I don't want to reinstall of them, I don't think this would be the only solution. There has to be another way to solve this.

Comment: Instead of a complete reinstall, do an in-place upgrade.

Comment: Are the necessary services running, such as Wireless Zero?

Comment: @PratyushNalam: what do you mean exactly with an in-place upgrade?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Wireless zero is running, yes. Is there any other service which should be running?

Comment: Network Location Awareness.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, it is running too

Comment: Something similar to Refresh on Windows 8. This Microsoft support articles describes it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255099

Answer (score 1):

The E6520 and E6320 have physical switches on them that control the wireless radio (on the right side of the laptop next to the keyboard). Have you made sure those are turn on? Since the device seems to be installed properly, perhaps the switch is just off.

Comment: No, that's not the case. They are turned on.